# Android OnClickListener errors

Tags: android, onclicklistener

I am trying to create and app using Fragments as a foundation and in one of these fragments I want to have a basic SQLite in which users can add memos.
I'm currently stuck on including the listener in the Java instead of the XML. I'm currently getting the following errors.

```
C:\Users\Luke\AndroidStudioProjects\ShardswithFragments\app\src\main\java\com\test\test\app\MemoFragment.java
Error:(43, 40) error: <identifier> expected
Error:(43, 41) error: illegal start of type
Error:(43, 44) error: ')' expected
Error:(43, 49) error: ';' expected
Error:(43, 50) error: invalid method declaration; return type required
Error:(44, 9) error: illegal start of expression
Error:(44, 16) error: illegal start of expression
Error:(44, 28) error: ';' expected
Error:(44, 35) error: ';' expected
Error:(51, 43) error: <identifier> expected
Error:(51, 44) error: illegal start of type
Error:(51, 47) error: ')' expected
Error:(51, 52) error: ';' expected
Error:(51, 53) error: invalid method declaration; return type required
Error:(52, 9) error: illegal start of expression
Error:(52, 16) error: illegal start of expression
Error:(52, 28) error: ';' expected
Error:(52, 35) error: ';' expected
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

It seems to be more syntax al errors and inability to resolve symbols (setOnClickListener) to be specific. Any help would be appreciated

```
 package com.test.test.app;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
 import android.view.LayoutInflater;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.view.ViewGroup;
 import android.widget.Button;  
 import android.widget.EditText;
 import android.widget.TextView;
 import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

 /**
   * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
   */
    public class MemoFragment extends Fragment{
        EditText Input;
        TextView LyricText;
        MyDBHandler dbHandler;
        Button addButtonClicked;
        Button deleteButtonClicked;


    public MemoFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor

    }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_memo, container, false);

        Input = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.Input);
        LyricText = (TextView) v.findViewById (R.id.LyricText);
        addButtonClicked = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.addButton);
        deleteButtonClicked = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.deleteButton);
        dbHandler = new MyDBHandler(getActivity() ,null, null, 1);
        printDatabase();
        return v;

    }
    //add to db
    addButtonClicked.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Lyrics lyrics = new Lyrics(Input.getText().toString());
            dbHandler.addLyric(lyrics);
            printDatabase();
        }};

    //delete from db
    deleteButtonClicked.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v){
            String inputtext = Input.getText().toString();
            dbHandler.deleteLyrics(inputtext);
            printDatabase();

        }};

    // printout entry
    public void printDatabase(){
        String dbString = dbHandler.databaseToString();
        LyricText.setText(dbString);
        Input.setText("");
    }

}
```

Comment: You are trying to add listener to a class field outside of any method. Move your setOnClickListener inside onCreateView

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't setup listener outside method scope, the right code is below

```
public class MemoFragment extends Fragment{
    EditText Input;
    TextView LyricText;
    MyDBHandler dbHandler;
    Button addButtonClicked;
    Button deleteButtonClicked;


public MemoFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor

}
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_memo, container, false);

    Input = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.Input);
    LyricText = (TextView) v.findViewById (R.id.LyricText);
    addButtonClicked = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.addButton);
    deleteButtonClicked = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.deleteButton);
    dbHandler = new MyDBHandler(getActivity() ,null, null, 1);
    printDatabase();

    //add to db
    addButtonClicked.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Lyrics lyrics = new Lyrics(Input.getText().toString());
            dbHandler.addLyric(lyrics);
            printDatabase();
        }
    });

    //delete from db
    deleteButtonClicked.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v){
            String inputtext = Input.getText().toString();
            dbHandler.deleteLyrics(inputtext);
            printDatabase();

        }
    });

    return v;
}

// printout entry
public void printDatabase(){
    String dbString = dbHandler.databaseToString();
    LyricText.setText(dbString);
    Input.setText("");
}

}
```

Comment: Thanks man really appreciate it